# Working of "===" operator

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

In `JavaScript` Programming language, I have seen the condition:

```
 if(data=== 'y')
```

I can't understand the operator `===`. Someone please explain the purpose of this operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `===` is used to determine that whether both the value and the data types are same or not whereas the operator `==` only checks for the value. See an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 2):

It means that the data types have to be same, as well as the values, for the expression to be true.

By the way, Java does not have this operator. Do you mean Javascript?